# I am trying to run project on a Jelly Bean emulator, and it crashes with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.transition.Explode

Tags: android, animation, material-design, android-transitions

My question is it possible to simply run on pre-Lollipop devices without transition and run on lollipop with transition or animation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){
    // Do something for froyo and above versions
} else{
    // do something for phones running an SDK before froyo
}
```

check API level or sdk version with this condition